# preg_match returns null when the haystack is an exec() output

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-match

I'm trying to run some regular expressions on the output of Linux commands that I ran using `exec()`. `preg_match` returns `NULL` when inserting the `exec()` output as a haystack, but when I put an identical copy of this output inside a string and use it as a haystack, `preg_match` works fine and outputs the expected array.

**Code:**

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i video.flv 2>&1 | grep Duration", $output);
//$output[0] will be: "Duration: 00:01:00.08, start: 0.042000, bitrate: 164 kb/s"    
$string = $output[0];    
//This regex is to extract the duration, "00:01:00", from the output.
$pattern = "/(^Duration:) ([^&]+)(.[0-9][0-9])(, start)/";    
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[2]);
//The result should be "00:01:00" but the whole $matches array is empty instead.

//If I added the result of output[0] manually into a string it works fine.
$str = "Duration: 00:01:00.08, start: 0.042000, bitrate: 164 kb/s";
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches_);
print_r($matches_[2]);
//Outputs "00:01:00" and everything is working fine.

//Just to make sure, I printed $str and $string to see if there is any difference
echo $str."\n".$string;
//The output is:
//Duration: 00:01:00.08, start: 0.042000, bitrate: 164 kb/s
//Duration: 00:01:00.08, start: 0.042000, bitrate: 164 kb/s
```

Comment: Try `trim`ing the string. You likely have some invisible characters at the start or end.

Comment: Have you checked the exact `$output`? Also, take a look at [FFprobe](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html), it can provide more nicely formatted output.

Comment: Thanks Dave. That worked. +1 for the answer. And I'll give FFprobe a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following echo command, using single quotes to separate the strings:

```
echo "'$str'\n'$string'";
```

Output:

```
'Duration: 00:01:00.08, start: 0.042000, bitrate: 164 kb/s'
'  Duration: 00:01:12.66, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 127 kb/s'
```

You see, they  aren't the same. ffmpeg adds whitespace in front of the string.

However, it doesn't matter if you change your pattern to:

```
$pattern = "/(Duration:) ([^&]+)(.[0-9][0-9])(, start)/";
```

Note that I've dropped the `^` in front of `Duration`. Now the pattern matches although there is some whitespace in front of the string.